# Django - Баг создания нескольких записей одновременными запросами

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Используется PostgreSQL, c уровнем изоляции serialisable. Алгоритм прост. Есть модель Django, в ней есть вьюшка. В вьюшке нужно создать запись в базе данных 1 раз, если её не существует.
Проблема в том, что джанга работает в нескольких процессах и при параллельной работе она создаёт их несколько записей, вместо одной, так как опять, работает в нескольких потоках. Через транзакции вроде не удаётся пофиксить, select_for_update с ними тоже. Вроде ситуация банальная, но подскажите что делать для безопасности?

```
def test(request):
  if not MyModel.objects.filter(value=100).exists():
    return HttpResponse(status=400)
  
  m = MyModel.objects.create(value=100)

  return JsonResponse({"id": m.id})
```

Comment: На уровне БД поставить же можно ограничения

Comment: Какие? @RottenRat

Comment: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-unique-constraint/